# Return reference to parameter

Tags: php

is any way to return reference at class parameter or global variable? I try this

```
class test{

  public static $var;

  public static function get(&$ref){

    $ref = self::$var;

  }

}

test::get($ref);
$ref = 'test';
var_dump(test::$var);
```

it's a basic example, i know, then this example can be use another way, but i need to keep principle

---

this is my function, where is problem with reference to variable

```
class mySession{

    public static function issetKeys(){

      $keys = func_get_args();

      $session = &$_SESSION;
      $c = 0;

      if (is_array($keys)){
        foreach ($keys as $val){

          if (isset($session[$val])){
            $session = &$session[$val];
            $c++;
          }
          else break;

        }
      }

      return $c == count($keys);

    }

    public static function &get(){

      $keys = func_get_args();

      $session = &$_SESSION;

      if (is_array($keys)){
        foreach ($keys as $val){

          if (!isset($session[$val])) $session[$val] = Array();
          $session = &$session[$val];

        }
      }

      return $session;

    }

  }

  function getValue(){

    if (!mySession::issetKeys('p1', 'p2')){
      $session = mySession::get('p1', 'p2');
      $session = 'string';
    }

    return mySession::get('p1', 'p2');

  }

  print_r($_SESSION);
```

but no variable save in to $_SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, a parameter only exists for the duration of the function to which it was passed; when the function returns, the call stack is unwound and the parameter disappears, which means that any reference to a variable that lived in the call stack will no longer be valid (since it points to memory which has been freed and now quite possibly contains something else entirely.)

That said, it *is* possible to return a reference to a parameter, although this will not work if you try to return a reference to a variable that actually lives in the stack (that is, one that was not passed by reference):

```
$myGlobal = 10;

// Note the & before the function name
function &returnReference(&$x) {
    return $x;
}

// Note the & before the function call
$someValue = &derp($myGlobal);
echo $myGlobal;

$someValue = 0;
echo $myGlobal;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, and *why would you ever do such a thing*?

If you want to access a public static variable, you'll just write

```
test::$var = "Hello there handsome";
```

In the case above you're not passing the reference of `this::$var` onto $ref, you're letting a reference to $ref contain the value of this::$var. PHP is not C, and references should generally be avoided when not necessary in PHP.

Comment: exactly this i now, then i wrote "example", for my using is global variable $_SESSION, where i map way to $_SESSION and i can return reference to $_SESSION, but i can, doesn't work, but if i save reference in to class variable, then is reference in class variable and others functions can change it

Comment: I'm sorry, English isn't my first language I can't really comprehend what you're saying.

Comment: my not either, see new example below